# Where is the git download of Google io 2013 android app with ActionBarCompat

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar-compat

From the recent google io 2013 video presentations on YouTube it was announced the android google io application was to be made available via git.
Most importantly this android application used ActionBarCompat.
I have just downloaded iosched and its using ABS (ActionBarSherlock)
have i got the wrong git url?

Comment: Take it from here, you can get started with these https://code.google.com/p/actionbarcompat/ or here, git hub link https://github.com/mariotaku/actionbarcompat

Comment: ABS has become the de-facto library for ActionBar considering its support and ease of integration compared with ActionBarCompat. I couldn't find the app on Google, but you can reverse engineer the app from Google Play ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The I/O 2013 source isn't out yet. When it's out, it'll be here: https://code.google.com/p/iosched/. The current code you downloaded is the 2012 app which does indeed use ActionBarSherlock.

It's likely blocked by the fact that ActionBarCompat, Google's action bar compatibility shim, also isn't out yet.

If I were a betting man I'd bet you'll see them drop very close to each other. You can follow the Android development Twitter, Google+ Page, Blog, website, etc. to find out when it's out. It'll make quite a splash when it does, it will take significant effort to actually miss the announcement.

Comment: Jake, thanks for taking the time to clarify the situation. I will be patient.

Answer (score 1):

ActionBarCompat has now been included in the Android Support Library rev 18!.

Find the information [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#)

`New v7 appcompat library:
Added ActionBar to allow implementation of the action bar user interface design pattern back to Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher. Use of this class requires that you implement your activity by extending the new ActionBarActivity class.`

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarCompat is now out.

DevBytes has a good summary on Android Developers here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TGgYqfJnyc

Or you can jump right into the reference doc here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html